# AppleLanguages no longer returns all languages

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6, ios8.1

in iOS7 `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"]` gave me an array of all languages. as of iOS8 this seems to have changed to the installed keyboards.

how can i still get an array of all languages in iOS8?

Comment: There is a bug eith global preferences in the iOS 8.1 simulator.  Are you seeing this on device or just the sim?

Comment: in the simulator i get an empty list (default config, i suspect if i add keyboards, the list may be populated), on the device i get the languages according to the keyboards that i have installed. if i run this on a iOS7 device, i get a full list. in the iOS7 sim i used to get the full list as well. i can no longer verify though as i have migrated to xcode6

Comment: You can install the iOS sim runtime in Xcode 6.  Goto Xcode->Preferences->Downloads.  As you are just seeing this in the iOS 8 sim, this is a known issue mentioned in the Xcode 6 release notes.

Comment: thank you for getting me the ios7 sim back, but i think i need to make myself clear: what i'm after is getting a full list of applelanguages on an ios8 device (ios8 sim would be nice, too) as was the case on ios7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `+[NSLocale preferredLanguages]` instead of querying NSUserDefaults.  Note that as mentioned in the Xcode 6.1 release notes, there is a known bug in the iOS 8.1 simulator runtime that prevents this from working there, but this will work as expected on other simulator versions and on device.

If you want a list of all supported languages rather than just the user's preferred ones, you can use `+[NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers]` which will return an NSArray of all supported locale identifiers.

Comment: i tried this. it returns a list of languages that represent the installed keyboards. this isn't it. any other ideas?

Comment: According to the documentation for NSLocale, it returns the list of user chosen languages in preference order.  It should not be returning anything related to keyboards.

Comment: be that as it may, as of ios sdk 8.1 i am looking for a way to find all  applelanguages as i did with ios sdk 7.1. here's the thing: in ios8 when you go to settings -> general -> language you can edit a list. in ios7 there was a tableview with all languages and you could just tick/select them. i want either the complete list like in ios7 or the list that i get when i press "add language..." in ios8

Comment: If you want a list of all supported locales, then it sounds like you want `+[NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers]`

Comment: thank you for your answer. regrettably, the list is now in excess of 650 items and no longer of use to me. should you know a way to generate a shorter list of languages, feel free to let me know

Comment: Then it's not really clear what you want.  Do you want the list of all available locales?  All available languages?  All available keyboards?  Selected locale?  Selected languages?  Selected keyboards?

Comment: a list of available languages not exceeding roughly 100 entries. the 100 most commonly used languages amongst iphone users would be ideal.

selected languages will not do as anyone speaking french and italian will only have either language installed. the list would not contain all languages spoken by the user.

a user's choice of languages is supposed to go on their profile. for that the ios7 list of languages was very practical. i have now taken that list as a constant array. the new list is way too large for any user to choose from when put into a uitableview